# Static noise when playing audio | Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, sound, pulseaudio

I know this is an old problem, but i had no success in resolving it.
I'm not an expert but i have faced some interesting behaviors.

- I hear the noise when i listen to music on Spotify. (I tried flatpack too)
- I can hear the noise when i play an audio YouTube/Spotify-web using Chrome.
- I CAN'T hear any noise when listening to music on YouTube using FIREFOX. But strangely enough, the problem shows up if i play music on Spotify Web App.
- The noise also doesn't show up when i play music with Rythmbox/VLC.

Hopefully these information could help some of the experts who are investigating this problem.
There was someone who claimed the problem is fixed in Pulse v.10+ but Ubuntu is still using v.0.9~. I didn't dig in any further into this claim, maybe someone else could confirm this

Also:
I'm using Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score -1):

I just installed pipewire-pulse (https://pipewire.org/) and restarted my Ubuntu 21.10.

```
sudo apt-get install pipewire-pulse
```

Solved the problem.